# Formula for possible number of combinations in alternating set of characters?

Tags: php, math, random, combinations

What's the formula for finding the possible number of combinations in this example: Generate 4 characters from A-Z and 0-9 but they will be alternating. Ex: L7W8, Q6N6, H3P1, etc..

To illustrate in PHP code:

```
$length = 4;

$pool_1 = explode(',', 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z');
$pool_2 = explode(',', '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0');

$s = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    $s.= ($i % 2) ? $pool_2[array_rand($pool_2)] : $pool_1[array_rand($pool_1)];        

echo $s;
```

If $length is 4, what's the formula to get the possible number of combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `26 * 10 * 26 * 10` for `length = 4`

Explanation:

for first position, you got 26 choices. for second, you got 10. possible variations : 26 * 10
for third position, you got 26 choices again. so you will get possible variations : ( 26 * 10 ) * 26

and so on..

This is basic [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics). Picking 1 out of 26 is indicated mathematically as `26C1` which equals `26/1 = 26`.

`NCR = (N.N-1.N-2 .. N-R-1)/(1.2.3 .. R)`

Answer (score 1):

The alternation does not affect the total number of choices.

It is simply 26*10*26*10.

If you disallow the repetition in letters, it'll be 26*10*25*10.

Answer (score 0):

For each character in your final string you multiply the number of possible insertions.

```
Choice of A-Z = 26
Choice of 0-9 = 10

Combining A-Z and 0-9:  26 * 10 = 260
Combining A-Z and A-Z:  26 * 26 = 676
Combining 0-9, A-Z, 0-9: 10 * 26 * 10 = 2600
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for unique combinations, then the formula will be:

(26 * 25) / 2! * (10 * 9) / 2! = 14625

Analysis:

The above formula assumes that you want unique combinations for both the letters and the numbers.  For example, B1A0 would be the first value in the sequence and Z9Y8 would be the last.  A0B1, A1B0, or B0A1 are all duplicates and not reflected in the above formula.  If these too can be allowed, then the formula is reduced to:

26 * 25 * 10 * 9 = 58500

If duplicate letters and numbers can be allowed, AA00 for example, then the formula would be:

26 * 26 * 10 * 10 = 67600

I would also suggest breaking up $length into two separate variables.  One variable would be for the letters and the other variable for the numbers.  So, for example if you are looking for unique combinations, then your code might look something like this:

```
$NumLetters = 26;
$NumNumbers = 10;
$LettersLen = 2;
$NumbersLen = 2;

$NumCombos = $NumLetters * ($NumLetters-1) / gmp_fact($LettersLen) * $NumNumbers * ($Numbers-1) / gmp_fact($NumbersLen);
```

If you know that $NumbersLen or $LettersLen is always 2, then you can eliminate the call to gmp_fact and replace it with the number 2.